# The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider for linked server was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: connection-string, distributed, distributed-transactions

I have a problem inserting some data into a linked server.
I'm getting the error message that appears on the title of the question.

1. I have tried to set the Local DTC properties

[image]

2. I have tried to set the Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction to False

[image]

It doesn't resolve the problem.

The interesting part is that if I create a new connection in the code to the database and use the Enlist=false it works

[image]

If I remove the `Enlist=false` from this connection in the code, it gives the same error, related to a distributed transaction.
The problem is that I would like to resolve this using the connection string from the `web.config` file, and I thought that if I added this Enlist to the `web.config connectionstring` it will work, but although the `connection string` is modified to use this `Enlist=false` parameter, I get the error

```
 <add name="" connectionString="..........Enlist=false;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />


 The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider for linked server was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
 OLE DB provider for linked server returned message "No transaction is active.".
```

Any help is appreciated!